# recursion exceeding the limit while iam trying to split my list into length of one

Tags: python

iam trying to write merge sort but its not working
why here when i run this code it's not splitting all the list and it is just repeating this form

```
ID_list=[5,8,9]
def merge_sort(Id_list):
  #define middle
 middle_index=len(ID_list)//2
  #split array into two parts (copies: left and right)
 left=ID_list[:middle_index]
 right=ID_list[middle_index:]
  #call merge sort for left
 print(left)
 print(right)
 merge_sort(left)
  #call merge sort for right
 merge_sort(right)
merge_sort(ID_list)

the output is below:

[5]
[8, 9]
[5]
[8, 9]
[5]
[8, 9]
[5]
[8, 9]
Recursion Error: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

what i need to have 
[5]
[8]
[9]
```

Comment: What? You're only splitting? Why don't you use a list comprehension?

Comment: a breaking condition is missing

Answer (score 0):

```
ID_list=[5,8,9]
```

So you want to split it in 1-value `list`s?

```
result = [[element] for element in ID_list]
```

Nothing hard.

Answer (score 0):

You mix up the variable identifiers. You have global list called `ID_list` and the parameter of the parameter function `Id_list`. The problem is that you never call the parameter of the function! To make it clear I renamed the parameter of the function as `lst`. Also a condition to exit the recursion is missing.

Here how to fix the recursion error:

```
def merge_sort(lst):
  #define middle
  middle_index=len(lst)//2
  if middle_index == 0: # breaking condition
    return
  #split array into two parts (copies: left and right)
  left=lst[:middle_index]
  right=lst[middle_index:]
  #call merge sort for left
  print(left)
  print(right)
  merge_sort(left)
  #call merge sort for right
  merge_sort(right)

ID_list=[5,8,9]
merge_sort(ID_list)
#[5]
#[8, 9]
#[8]
#[9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mising a return statement or break condition in your function. You need to add following lines to the beginning of your function:

```
def merge_sort(ID_list):
  if len(ID_list) == 1:
    return
```